# How to force body to be the size of the screen when partially filled in?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I would like to build a site where there is a fixed header, a variable content and a footer which is at the bottom when the page is not completely filled in. I will use the [CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) for that.

Expanding the content element when the height is known is easy:

```css
div {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
}

#container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>hello </div>
  <div>world</div>
  <div>three</div>
</div>
```

I then tried to reproduce this on a full window browser and I do not know how to tell the application "*the height is the size of the browser if there is not enough content, otherwise this is the content*". I thought that `min-height: 100%;` applied to the `body` would be fine - but it is not:

```
body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.navbar {
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 2;
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 3;
}
.main {
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: 3;
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 2;
}
.toc {
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: 3;
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 3;
}
.footer {
    grid-row-start: 3;
    grid-row-end: 4;
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 3;
}
```

This code creates the right grid, but the size of `body` is not the whole height of the browser:

[image]

Comment: Could you try using `viewport` units on the `body`? 100vh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `min-height:100%`, use `min-height: 100vh`.

Percentage heights are tricky, as they often require a defined height on the parent element ([full explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)).

From the spec:

> [**5.1.2. Viewport-percentage lengths: the `vw`, `vh`, `vmin`, `vmax` units**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)
>
> The viewport-percentage lengths are relative to the size of the
>   initial containing block. When the height or width of the initial
>   containing block is changed, they are scaled accordingly.
>
> - **vw unit** - Equal to 1% of the width of the initial containing block.
> - **vh unit** - Equal to 1% of the height of the initial containing
>     block.
> - **vmin unit** - Equal to the smaller of `vw` or `vh`.
> - **vmax unit** - Equal to the larger of `vw` or `vh`.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. The worst is that I did try to use `vh` like in your answer, but forgot that the total is 100 and not 1 (I put `min-height: 1vh`)  - probably because of having used `fr` before (where 1 would be "all that remains")